# python drop down from csv file header

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, dropdown, optionmenu

I am trying to create a drop down list with selected csv files header using tkinter

```
def clickpath():
   # window.filePath =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("all files","*.*")))
    filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathin.delete(0,END)
    pathin.insert(0,filename)
```

I want to create an option Menu to use the pathin.get() as the list..
however I can't make it work
can some one help ?
Thanks so  much !

I had something like this ..but not sure how to call it properly ...

```
var = StringVar(window)
var2 = StringVar(window)
option = OptionMenu(window,var2,"test")
option.grid(column=4,row=11)
option.pack()

var.set("column")

file = pathin.get()

def test():
    global var 
    column =var.get()
    with open(colum,"rt") as f:
        var2 = read.csv.DictReader(f)
        return var2
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share a code which we can use to reproduce your issue and help you.